# What is the proper way of installing Xamarin because I am getting an error every time that I try to start

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, installation, xamarin.android

I am trying to develop my first Android/iOS app using Xamarin, however every time that I try to create a new project and open up the Main.axml in the Resources -> Layout folders, I get an error stating that "Something went wrong"

[Something Went Wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2K4m.png)

I have tried re-installing Visual Studio as well as Xamarin but I have had no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you have already installed the Android SDK, you might need to (Inside Visual Studio) go to Tools -> Options, in the left side on that new window that opens Expand Xamarin.  Click on Android Settings and Make sure all the Locations are set for Java Development, Android SDK, and NDK Location.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Android SDK. You can get it from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads)

Answer (score 0):

If you have already installed the Android SDK, you might need to (Inside Visual Studio) go to Tools -> Options, in the left side on that new window that opens Expand Xamarin. Click on Android Settings and Make sure all the Locations are set for Java Development, Android SDK, and NDK Location.  Point your Android SDK location to where you installed it.

Comment: I am trying to locate the SDK and NDK locations, however I am having no luck in doing so. I believe that I have them installed, I just can't find the correct path.

Comment: I think the location it defaulted to for me was C:\AndroidSDK\  might look there but I may have selected that on my own.